# SDL/OpenGL floating point exception

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I am programming a simple pong game in C++ (SDL/OpenGL), however I have run into a problem compiling on Ubuntu. I get a floating point exception when I use `SDL_OPENGL` as the flag for `SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_OPENGL);` It's being compiled with g++, and it seems to compile fine with Visual C++ (no errors).

Here is my code:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>

const int WIDTH = 640;
const int HEIGHT = 480;

struct Paddle
{
    float x, y, w, h;
    Paddle(float a, float b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        w = 10;
        h = 80;
    }
};

struct Ball
{
    float x, y, r;
    float velx, vely;
    Ball(float a, float b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        r = 7;
        velx = (float)0.2;
        vely = (float)0.2;
    }
};

bool testCollision(Ball b, Paddle p)
{
    if (b.x + b.r < p.x) return false;
    if (b.x > p.x + p.w) return false;
    if (b.y + b.r < p.y) return false;
    if (b.y > p.y + p.h) return false;
    return true;
}

void init()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Pong~~", NULL);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_OPENGL);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    //glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    init();

    Paddle p1(10.0, 80.0);
    Paddle p2(620.0, 80.0);
    Ball b(50, 50);

    bool press[4] = {false, false, false, false};

    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    running = false;
                    break;

                case SDLK_w:
                    press[0] = true;
                    break;

                case SDLK_s:
                    press[1] = true;
                    break;

                case SDLK_UP:
                    press[2] = true;
                    break;

                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    press[3] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            else if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
            {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_w:
                    press[0] = false;
                    break;

                case SDLK_s:
                    press[1] = false;
                    break;

                case SDLK_UP:
                    press[2] = false;
                    break;

                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    press[3] = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Logic
        if (press[0] == true) p1.y -= (float)0.2;
        if (press[1] == true) p1.y += (float)0.2;
        if (press[2] == true) p2.y -= (float)0.2;
        if (press[3] == true) p2.y += (float)0.2;

        if (p1.y < 0) p1.y = 0;
        else if (p1.y + p1.h > HEIGHT) p1.y = HEIGHT - p1.h;
        if (p2.y < 0) p2.y = 0;
        else if (p2.y + p2.h > HEIGHT) p2.y = HEIGHT - p2.h;

        b.x += b.velx;
        b.y += b.vely;

        if (b.x < 0) b.velx = -b.velx;
        else if (b.x + b.r > WIDTH) b.velx = -b.velx;
        if (b.y < 0) b.vely = -b.vely;
        else if (b.y + b.r > HEIGHT) b.vely = -b.vely;

        if (testCollision(b, p1) == true) b.velx = -b.velx;
        else if (testCollision(b, p2) == true) b.velx = -b.velx;
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glPushMatrix();

        //Draw ball
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor4ub(255, 5, 255, 255);
            glVertex2f(b.x, b.y);
            glVertex2f(b.x + b.r, b.y);
            glVertex2f(b.x + b.r, b.y + b.r);
            glVertex2f(b.x, b.y + b.r);
        glEnd();

        //Draw paddles
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor4ub(255, 5, 5, 255);
            glVertex2f(p1.x, p1.y);
            glVertex2f(p1.x + p1.w, p1.y);
            glVertex2f(p1.x + p1.w, p1.y + p1.h);
            glVertex2f(p1.x, p1.y + p1.h);

            glVertex2f(p2.x, p2.y);
            glVertex2f(p2.x + p2.w, p2.y);
            glVertex2f(p2.x + p2.w, p2.y + p2.h);
            glVertex2f(p2.x, p2.y + p2.h);
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? What line do you get the error on? Is it always the same line? What are the expression and values it crashes on?

Comment: The floating point exception was obscure, but I determined that the error occurs at the line `SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_OPENGL);`. Namely, the SDL_OPENGL flag is causing the error in the g++ compiler.

Comment: What flags are you compiling this with? `-lSDL -lGL`?

Comment: Why are you `#include`ing `SDL_opengl.h` *and* `GL.h`?  You only need `SDL_opengl.h`.  It pulls in the proper platform-specific GL headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

First off, I misspoke. When I said it wasn't compiling, it was; the program was actually not running, giving me an ambiguous "floating point exception" error in the terminal on Ubuntu 11.10. After researching the problem for hours with my friend, to no avail, I gave it one last attempt and updated my graphics driver. Yup, that fixed everything.

To update my AMD (fglrx) graphics driver, I simply opened up terminal and typed in:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates-dev
```

Go ahead and restart, and activate the proprietary graphics driver!